# Setting Timeout to fs.copy function

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, async-await, timeout

```
      global.resultArr = {};
      global.failedArr = [];
      global.successArr = [];    
       const writeFile = async function (dirResult, queryResult) {
  for (i = 0; i < queryResult.recordset.length; i++) {
    for (file of dirResult) {
      if (
        file.substring(file.length - 3) == "wav" &&
        global.failedArr.indexOf(queryResult.recordset[i].ip_vch) == -1
      ) {
        try {
          const writeResult = await timeout(
            fs.copy(
              dir + "//" + file,
              "//" +
                queryResult.recordset[i].ip_vch +
                "//RXWaveFiles//DynamicLibraries" +
                "//" +
                libid +
                "//" +
                file
            ),
            5000
          );
          if (
            writeResult &&
            global.failedArr.indexOf(queryResult.recordset[i].ip_vch) == -1
          ) {
            console.log(queryResult.recordset[i].ip_vch);
            global.failedArr.push(queryResult.recordset[i].ip_vch);
            await sql.query`update opower..dialers set fileMoveResult_int=0 where ip_vch =${queryResult.recordset[i].ip_vch}`;
          } else if (
            global.successArr.indexOf(queryResult.recordset[i].ip_vch) == -1 &&
            global.failedArr.indexOf(queryResult.recordset[i].ip_vch) == -1
          ) {
            global.successArr.push(queryResult.recordset[i].ip_vch);
            await sql.query`update opower..dialers set fileMoveResult_int=1 where ip_vch =${queryResult.recordset[i].ip_vch}`;
            console.log("success!" + queryResult.recordset[i].ip_vch);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
          if (global.failedArr.indexOf(queryResult.recordset[i].ip_vch) == -1) {
            global.failedArr.push(queryResult.recordset[i].ip_vch);
            await sql.query`update opower..dialers set fileMoveResult_int=0 where ip_vch =${queryResult.recordset[i].ip_vch}`;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  global.resultArr.success = successArr;
  global.resultArr.failed = failedArr;
  return global.resultArr;
};

    // utility function that creates a promise that rejects after a certain time
    function timeoutPromise(t, errMsg = "timeout") {
        // create possible error object here to get appropriate stack trace
        let e = new Error(errMsg);
        e.timeout = true;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(reject, t, e);
        });
    }

// wrap a promise with a timeout, pass promise, time in ms and 
// optional timeout error message
function timeout(p, t, errMsg = "timeout") {
    return Promise.race(p, timeoutPromise(t, errMsg));
}
```

I am using this await function in a for loop in which from  a source directory I need to copy some files to multiple network directories, however the problem here with await is that for the directories it is failing it's taking almost a minute to resolve and then gives the control back for the next iteration, is there a way we could stop the current iteration after 5 seconds.

Comment: What's the goal here?  You wan't to abort a single `fs.copy()` or all the  `fs.copy()` operations if they take over 5 seconds?  Please show us your actual code in the loop and what you're trying to accomplish (write a mini-spec for how you want it to behave).  That sounds very bizarre that you'd abort copying a directory if it takes over 5 seconds.

Comment: This is is the code block in which I am fetching different directories from database and then in all of those directories i need to copy some files and update the result as whether the file is copied or not but the catch is for the directories it is failing to copy, i am getting the reponse very late and due to that the control remains in the loop, i need break the for loop iteration after certain time

Comment: What is `fs.copy()` and where does it come from?  The `fs` module has `fs.copyFile()` and `fs.promises.copyFile()`, not `fs.copy()`.

Comment: So, if you're `fs.copy()` is taking more than 5 seconds, what do you want to do?  Abort the entire loop?

Comment: const fs = require('fs-extra')

Comment: Yes, I need to stop the execution then update the database that it's failed for this directory and go to next iteration in the loop

Comment: Please undo all the changes you just made to your question.  Your question was asked, answered and accepted and your question should not be further modified.  To ask an additional question about modified code, please write a NEW question and show the new modified code and ask the new question there.

Comment: sure, just did that

Comment: 3 hours ago, you did a big edit of your question.  That's the one I asked you to rollback.  When you file a new question about your new issue, if you drop a comment here tagged for me I will look at your new question.  It doesn't seem like you've added a new question yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an error timeout to any promise like this:

```
// utility function that creates a promise that rejects after a certain time
function timeoutPromise(t, errMsg = "timeout") {
    // create possible error object here to get appropriate stack trace
    let e = new Error(errMsg);
    e.timeout = true;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(reject, t, e);
    });
}

// wrap a promise with a timeout, pass promise, time in ms and 
// optional timeout error message
function timeout(p, t, errMsg = "timeout") {
    return Promise.race([p, timeoutPromise(t, errMsg)]);
}
```

The, you would use this with your `fs.copy()` like this:

```
const writeResult = await timeout(fs.copy(...), 5000);
```

So, then if the `fs.copy()` is taking more than 5 seconds, the promise you are awaiting will reject and you can catch it in your `catch` handler and act accordingly.  You will be able to see that the error object has a `.timeout` property.

The way this works is that the `timeout()` function creates a race between the promise you passed in and another promise that will reject after your timeout expires.  The first one to complete controls the output of `Promise.race()` and thus controls what you are using `await` on.  If the timeout wins, then the promise will be rejected.

Comment: I added these two functions in my try block and now the copy function failing for every directory and error is <Promise> is not iterable

Comment: @DeepanshuWadhwa - First off, you don't put these two functions inside your existing function.  Put them in some shared location that you can access.  Then, for me to help further, you'd have to show me the actual code you tried.  You can add it to the end of your question (don't replace what you have, add it to the end) and post a comment to me when you've modified the question.

Comment: @DeepanshuWadhwa - I fixed an error in my code.  The two promises being passed to `Promise.race()` have to be in an array.  That would explain the error message you got.

Comment: is there any way we could make the request asynchronous and still be able to update the result in the database correctly, i am trying promise.all for requests but it is showing me pending result at console.